# Advanced Filter array of objects based on condition if its nested object has required property in it

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, object

I am trying to solve a difficult computation but i am not reaching anywhere. can someone please help

Here is a simple example.

```
const filterCityBy = "NY";
const data = [ 
  { name: "Harry, age: 45, city: "NY" },
  { name: "Mike, age: 36, city: "CA" }
]

const filteredData = data.filter(x = x.city === filterCityBy);

output = [ { name: "Harry, age: 45 } ]
```

This is self explainatory. I am trying to filter `data` with value `filterCityBy` and getting the desired `output`

But my requirement is as follows

```
const filterCityBy = "NY";
const data = [ 
  { name: "Harry, age: 45, totalCities: [{ city: "NY"}]},
  { name: "Mike, age: 36, totalCities: [{ city: "NY"}, {city: "CA"} }] }
]

output = [ { name: "Harry, age: 45 }, { name: "Mike, age: 36 } ]
```

How can i achieve the desired output. Harry and Mike both has city as `NY` in their `totalCities` array. I only need their `name` and `age` once the city is present in their `totalCities` array.

Can someone please help on how to get this.

Comment: what is with `totalCities` later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if *some* of the `totalCities` matches `filterCityBy`.

Then use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to get only the `name` and `age` key by removing `totalCities` using [a destructuring assignment (`...r`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring):

```js
const filterCityBy = "NY";
const data = [ 
  { name: "Harry", age: 45, totalCities: [{ city: "NY"}]},
  { name: "Mike", age: 36, totalCities: [{ city: "NY"}, {city: "CA"} ] }
]

const output = data
    .filter(p => p?.totalCities.some(({ city }) => city === filterCityBy))
    .map(({ totalCities, ...r }) => r);
                   
console.log(output);
```

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Harry",
    "age": 45
  },
  {
    "name": "Mike",
    "age": 36
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could filter the array and map the result without `totalCities`.

```js
const
    filterCityBy = "NY";
    data = [{ name: "Harry", age: 45, totalCities: [{ city: "NY" }] }, { name: "Mike", age: 36, totalCities: [{ city: "NY" }, { city: "CA" }] }],
    result = data
        .filter(({ totalCities }) => totalCities.some(({ city }) => city === filterCityBy))
        .map(({ totalCities, ...o}) => o);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your example code and result. The `filter` method alone would not give that result once you fix the code. You would need the `map` method as well, as pointed out by others already. Here is another way you can do it:

```js
const 
    filterCityBy = "NY",
    data = [ 
      { name: "Harry", age: 45, totalCities: [{ city: "NY"}]},
      { name: "Mike", age: 36, totalCities: [{ city: "NY"}, {city: "CA"}] }
    ],
    
    filteredData = data.filter(
        ({totalCities}) => totalCities.some(({city}) => city === filterCityBy)
    )
    .map(({name,age}) => ({name,age}));
    
console.log( filteredData );
```

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid mapping to object without `totalCities`. Just don't use `totalCities` in the filtered array. Also it's questionable whether the mapping could help memory optimization. Also destructuring could mean more verbose and complex syntax.

```
` Chrome/119
----------------------------------------------------------
Alexander     1.00x  |  x10000000  181  188  190  202  216
Nina Scholz   1.70x  |  x10000000  307  311  313  314  319
----------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
const
    filterCityBy = "NY";
    data = [{ name: "Harry", age: 45, totalCities: [{ city: "NY" }] }, { name: "Mike", age: 36, totalCities: [{ city: "NY" }, { city: "CA" }] }];
    
// @benchmark Nina Scholz

filteredData = data.filter(
        ({totalCities}) => totalCities.some(({city}) => city === filterCityBy)
    )
    .map(({name,age}) => ({name,age}));
    
// @benchmark Alexander
data.filter(p => p.totalCities.some(e => e.city === filterCityBy))

/*@end*/eval(atob('e2xldCBlPWRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHkucXVlcnlTZWxlY3Rvcigic2NyaXB0Iik7aWYoIWUubWF0Y2hlcygiW2JlbmNobWFya10iKSl7bGV0IHQ9ZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgic2NyaXB0Iik7dC5zcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmpzZGVsaXZyLm5ldC9naC9zaWxlbnRtYW50cmEvYmVuY2htYXJrL2xvYWRlci5qcyIsdC5kZWZlcj0hMCxkb2N1bWVudC5oZWFkLmFwcGVuZENoaWxkKHQpfX0='));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```